# How to modify cluster item total sum value?

Tags: android, google-maps, markerclusterer

Currently I'm using google maps utils to implement markers and their clustering in the map.

The question is that I want only some of those markers to count for the total sum of the cluster density.

I was looking to make the decision process based on the markers tag, but I can't seem to find no way to alter the total marker count in each cluster.

Is there any way to do this?

Thank you

Comment: Why don't you try to add non-clustered markers directly to map and other ones to the ClusterManager as an item?

Comment: Yes, I should have been more explicit about this. I really want them added to the ClusterManager, because if not, if zoomed out, these markers will show along the cluster items and I don't want them like that. I want them all to share the cluster funcionality.

Comment: I may not be understanding you but if I were you, instead of making clustering decision based on tags, I use two different ClusterManager-s. As far as I understand, you want to cluster some specific markers in a cluster and the ones in another. Am I right?

Comment: No. Example: I have 5 markers that derive from the same cluster. 4 of them are red and one green, and I want only the cluster to show the number of red markers, but at the same time all these 5 markers should derive from the same cluster.

Comment: Ah, I see. Should you strictly use the default cluster view or is it possible to use a custom view?

Comment: I can use a custom view there is no problem doing that. Do you think it is possible to do it that way?

Comment: Ok, so I'm thinking to use onBeforeClusterRendered to make the count of the items that I want and use a custom view where I'm putting that counter. Thanks for all the help, I'll say something how it went!

Comment: Yay, you're right. See my answer below. You should implement some trivial parts by yourself but I think it still gives an idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `ClusterRenderer` override `onBeforeClusterRendered` as follows:

```
@Override
protected void onBeforeClusterRendered(Cluster<MyClusterItem> cluster,
                                       MarkerOptions markerOptions) {

    // Calculate totalSum by checking the color of item
    int totalSum = 0;
    for (MyClusterItem item : cluster) {
        // Assume each MyClusterItem holds an attribute -- String color --.
        // Also, assume you can get this attribute by using the following method.
        if (item.getColorAsString().equals("red")) {
            totalSum++;
        }
    }

    // Write a method to customize your cluster drawable according to totalSum.
    Drawable customDrawable = customizeClusterDrawable(totalSum);
    mClusterImageView.setImageDrawable(customDrawable);
    Bitmap icon = mClusterIconGenerator.makeIcon(String.valueOf(cluster.getSize()));
    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(icon));
}
```

Comment: This what I was doing now, but I'll accept your answer because it due to your guidance that I found this way of doing it...Really really thanks for the help!!! How can I accept your answer?

Comment: By clicking the check mark on the left of the answer. Thanks. But I'm not sure that accepting answer is possible with your reputation score. If not, I'm okay. I'm glad to be of help.